# H.264 level for 1920x1080 60 video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, x264

According H.264 specifications, 1920x1080 60p video should use Level 4.2 (2,048×1,080@60).

However some old hardware players (e.g. Popcorn Hour A-210) can play 1920x1080 60p videos created only with Level 4.1.

By default, ffmpeg/libx264 automatically sets Level 4.2 for a created 1920x1080 60p videos.

Should I manually change Level to 4.1 for such video for better compatibility?

Answer (score 3):

kind of an opinion based question. Personally, I wouldn’t. Because there may be players out that that can’t  play a 4.2 stream and attempting to play would result in undefined bevaviour.

If however, you are willing to accept that sometimes you may get corrupt output, or av sync problems, or worst case a crash, then go for it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.